# Upper Bound on Expected Value of $n$ i.i.d. Poisson random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $\{X_i \}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. from a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$ and let $$M_n = \max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i.$$
What is a tight upper bound on $\mathbb{E}[M_n]$? I can prove that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[M_n] \le \frac{(\lambda+1) \log n}{\log \log n} + O \left( \frac{1}{\log \log n} \right)
\end{equation} 
but numerically this bound is not tight. Can someone give a tighter analysis or point to a reference with one?

**Proof of my bound:**

Let $s > 0$. Then by Jensen's inequality,
$$ e^{s \mathbb{E}[M_n]} \le \mathbb{E}[e^{sM_n}] \le \sum_{i-1}^n \mathbb{E}[e^{sX_i}] = ne^{\lambda(e^s-1)}$$
from the moment generating function. Then taking the logarithm of both sides gives
$$ \mathbb{E}[M_n] \le \frac{\log n}s + \frac{\lambda(e^s-1)}{s}.$$
Finally, the minimum of the function on the right hand side should be around $s = \log \log n$ which gives the bound above.

Comment: Some back of the envelope calculations lead me to believe that is the right asymptotic growth.  What numerics do you have to show it's not tight?  Is it the $\log n/ \log \log n$ asymptotic or just the constant $\lambda+1$?

Comment: Just the constant $\lambda + 1$. I do think its $O(\log n / \log \log n)$.

Comment: Does the constant 1 match better?  You're clearly losing something by going from max to sum.

Comment: 1 is definitely too small. Also the constant should depend on $\lambda$.

Comment: Are you sure?  Take a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4373.pdf  Apparently $M_n$ becomes super concentrated as $n \to \infty$ and with high probability lies in an interval of length 1 located $~ \log n /\log \log n$ independent of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4373.pdf mentions that as $n \to \infty$, $M_n$ becomes concentrated at two adjacent values located asymptotically at $\sim \log n/ \log \log n$ independent of $\lambda$ with probability approaching 1.  Even tighter estimates are given there.

Comment: Hmm interesting, can you clarify how tight the bounds are exactly? The paper does not give much detail on the rate of convergence

Comment: You can see from the Figure 3.  It's really tight apparently.  They claim the formula they give has error less than 1 (at least over the values of $n$ and $\lambda$ in that figure).  They don't seem to offer much in the way of proofs.

Answer (score 1):

After the fact, but a quick observation: in your proof, set instead
$$
s \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \log\left(\frac{\log n}{\lambda}+1\right) 
$$
Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[M_n] \leq \frac{\log n}{s} + \frac{\lambda(e^s-1)}{s}
= \frac{2\log n}{s} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} 2\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
which is better than your bound for $\lambda >1$.